# Correlation frequencies with two different groups?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, dispersion

Have a dataset similar to this:

```
LETTER FREQ  GROUPS   ESPECIE
A      3     GROUP 1     X
B      3     GROUP 1     X
C      4     GROUP 1     X
A      4     GROUP 2     T
B      5     GROUP 2     T
C      6     GROUP 2     T
A      6     GROUP 3     T
---
```

I would like to correlate the frequency of the letter A of the X species with the frequency of the letter A of the T species. And in the end I would just have a graph. In that case, would you have to make an average? Is it possible to calculate the correlation with the averages, does this compromise the result? How could you analyze this data?

Comment: What is the role of the `FREQ` and `GROUPS` variables in your question?  What exactly do you mean by "correlate"?  What kind of graph do you envision?

Comment: @whuber Negative correlation is a relationship between two variables freq A and freq B and different species. freq A - especie X VS freq B - and especie T;
BUT THERE ARE DIFFERENT GROUPS FOR EACH SPECIES... scatter plot or barplot